# How to find the date after the last occurrence of a certain observation in R?

Tags: r

I have data grouped using dplyr in R. I would like to find the 'date' after the last occurrence of observations ('B') equal to or greater than 1 (1, 2, 3 or 4) in each group ('A'). In other words, the 'date' where 1/2/3/4 has turned to 0.

Simply finding the date for the first occurrence of 0 will not work as in some groups 1/2/3/4 switches to 0 and then back again and does not give the result I'd like.

I would like this 'date' for each group to be given in a new column ('date.after').

For example, given the following sample of data, grouped by A (this has been simplified, my data is actually grouped by 3 variables):

```
A  B  date
a  2  1
a  2  2
a  1  5
a  0  8
b  3  1
b  3  4
b  3  6 
b  0  7 
b  0  9
c  1  2 
c  1  3
c  1  4
```

I would like to achieve the following:

```
A  B  date date.after
a  2  1    8
a  2  2    8
a  1  5    8
a  0  8    8
b  3  1    7
b  3  4    7
b  3  6    7
b  0  7    7
b  0  9    7
c  1  2    NA
c  1  3    NA
c  1  4    NA
```

I hope this makes sense, thank you all very much for your help! 
This post may look familiar, I have just asked a very similar question:

[How to find the last occurrence of a certain observation in grouped data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649207/how-to-find-the-last-occurrence-of-a-certain-observation-in-grouped-data-in-r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a dplyr option:

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(date_after = date[last(which(B >= 1)) + 1])
#Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
#Groups: A [3]
#
#        A     B  date date_after
#   (fctr) (int) (int)      (int)
#1       a     2     1          8
#2       a     2     2          8
#3       a     1     5          8
#4       a     0     8          8
#5       b     3     1          7
#6       b     3     4          7
#7       b     3     6          7
#8       b     0     7          7
#9       b     0     9          7
#10      c     1     2         NA
#11      c     1     3         NA
#12      c     1     4         NA
```

Alternatively, you could use dplyr's `nth` function:

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(date_after = nth(date, last(which(B >= 1)) + 1))
```

What it does (in both cases): It computes the position of the last entry of `B` equal to or greater than 1, then adds 1 to that index and returns `date` of that position. It returns `NA` if that position is not available (as is the case in the last group).

You can do exactly the same in data.table using:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, date_after := date[last(which(B >= 1)) + 1], by = A]
```

Comment: Nice, here is an equivalent base R solution `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, data$A), function(x){ x$date.after = x$date[tail(which(x$B >= 1),1) + 1]; x}))`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar, thanks, that's a good suggestion except you would need to replace `last` with `tail(..., 1)` because `last` are functions in `dplyr` and `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

I went with dplyr since I think the code is easier to read than data.table

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(
    Date0 = date[B == 0][1]
  )
```

Comment: A quote from the Q: "Simply finding the date for the first occurrence of 0 will not work "